# How to count unique integers in a string using hive?

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive

Trying to count the unique bytes in a string?

**DATA (Phone numbers for example with only numeric bytes):**

```
1234567890
1111111112
```

**Results:**

```
10
2
```

I have tried the below and it didn't work because the sum() won't accept the UDF '**if**' with in it, I think.

```
 select phone
 , sum(
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'0',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'1',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'2',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'3',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'4',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'5',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'6',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'7',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'8',''))<10,'1','0') as int) +
        cast(if(length(regexp_replace(phone,'9',''))<10,'1','0') as int)         
       )  as unique_bytes
 from table;
```

I am not apposed to regular expressions as a solution either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` . . . but like this:

```
select phone,
       ((case when phone like '%0%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%1%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%2%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%3%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%4%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%5%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%6%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%7%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%8%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when phone like '%9%' then 1 else 0 end) +
       ) as ints
 from table;
```

Your code has several issues:

- `sum()` is an aggregation function and is not needed.
- The `if()` is returning strings, but you are adding the values together.
- I'm not sure why you are using `regexp_replace()` rather than just `replace()`.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the quick response.  No need for the sum in the equation at all.  I realized almost right after I picked enter.  However, your solution is going down a much better path and is more efficient!  Thanks.

Comment: I noticed the sum issue right away when I posted.  Silly me.  The 'if' part does return a string, that is why I cast as integer.  As far as using regexp_replace as apposed to replace, I use a lot of regex and was just defaulting to habit.  Thanks again for the solution.  It is  more efficient than mine for sure, I wish I had seen it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with tab1 as (
select stack(3,
'1','1234567890',
'2','1111111112',
'3','2222222223') as (col0, col1))
select tab1.col0, count(distinct tf.col) from tab1 lateral view explode(split(tab1.col1,'')) tf as col
where tf.col regexp '\\d'
group by tab1.col0
```

[image]